# Laravel Eloquent select use group by

Tags: laravel, select, group-by, eloquent

When I query the database I get the results I want.

```
 $data['jobtypes'] = User::Select('jobtype_search', DB::raw('count(jobtype_search) as jobs'))->
        Where('jobtype_search', '<>', '')
            ->GroupBy('jobtype_search')
            ->get();
```

However, when I do not want to keep calling the database for every query.  Instead I call on the database once to get the chunk of data I need and then query off that.

```
$user = User::whereBetween('created_at', [$start_date, $end_date])->get();
```

When I try

```
 $data['jobtype_search'] =$user->Select('jobtype_search', DB::raw('count(jobtype_search) as jobs'))->
        Where('jobtype_search', '<>', '')
            ->GroupBy('jobtype_search')
            ->get();
```

I get a `method select not found` error.

What should I change so my query works?

Comment: What does the $user variable hold?

Comment: @devk all data from the Users table between two dates.  In this case the end date is today and the start date is 30 days ago.

Comment: What would be wrong with just moving that `whereBetween` call to the first query?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$user` variable in your example is the result set (a Laravel collection) of the query, but you're trying to use it as a query.

This would work (another query):

```
$data['jobtype_search'] = User::whereBetween('created_at', [$start_date, $end_date])
    ->Select('jobtype_search', DB::raw('count(jobtype_search) as jobs'))
    ->Where('jobtype_search', '<>', '')
    ->GroupBy('jobtype_search')
    ->get();
```

Or if you want to do it on the result set, you could do it with the [collection methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#available-methods) on the result set:

```
$data['jobtype_search'] = $user
    ->filter(function ($item) {
        return $item->jobtype_search !== '';
    })
    ->groupBy('jobtype_search')
    ->map(function ($item, $jobTypeSearch) {
        return [
            'jobtype_search' => $jobTypeSearch,
            'jobs' => $item->count(),
        ];
    })
```